# calculating with column aliases in sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, alias

I'm working on a hobby project to teach myself programming and sql.
It's an app that lets you create units and build an army for a d&d expansion.
my problem is that the cost of a unit is derived from its attributes (attack, power, defense, toughness, morale) which are in turn derived from several variables (its ancestry(Dwarf), experience (veteran), equipment (heavy) and type(infantry).

this is the code I came up with, the statement I am asking about is the second one:

```
def display_unit(connection, rowid:int):
rowid = str(rowid)
with connection:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT name, ancestry, experience, equipment, type FROM units WHERE rowid = ?;""", rowid)
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    (name, ancestry, experience, equipment, type) = result
    print(f"{name}:\t{ancestry} {experience} {equipment} {type}")
    print("Army: \n")
    print("Attack  Power  Defense  Toughness  Morale  Cost")
    cursor.execute("""SELECT 
    (ancestry.attack + experience.attack + equipment.attack + type.attack) AS attack,
    (ancestry.power + experience.power + equipment.power + type.power) AS power,
    (ancestry.defense + experience.defense + equipment.defense + type.defense) AS defense,
    (ancestry.toughness + experience.toughness + equipment.toughness + type.toughness) AS toughness,
    (ancestry.morale + experience.morale + equipment.morale + type.morale) AS morale,
    ((((attack + power + defense + toughness + (morale*2)) * type.costmp) * size.costmp) * 10 + 30) as cost
    FROM units
    JOIN ancestry on units.ancestry = ancestry.ancestry
    JOIN experience on units.experience = experience.experience
    JOIN equipment on units.equipment = equipment.equipment
    JOIN type on units.type = type.type
    JOIN size on units.size = size.size
    WHERE units.rowid = ?; 
    
    """, (rowid))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    (attack, power, defense, toughness, morale, cost) = result
    print(f"   {attack:1}{power:7}{defense:8}{toughness:10}{morale:10}{cost:8}")
```

so to calculate the cost of the unit I want to use the alias for the combined stats, but apparently you can't calculate with an alias in the same select statement where you define it.
Now I COULD probably copy the lines where I create the column alias and insert those into the formula, but that would turn this into such a mess of a statement that I cannot believe that whoever created sqlite didn't think of it and come up with a clever way to not have to do that.
What is the correct way to calculate the units' cost here??

EDIT:
Shawn's solution worked.
I now have a function to get the stats first:

```
def get_stats(connection): #creates a new view of all the units' stats
    with connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""DROP VIEW IF EXISTS stats;""")
        cursor.execute("""CREATE VIEW stats AS SELECT
        (ancestry.attack + experience.attack + equipment.attack + type.attack) AS attacktotal,
        (ancestry.power + experience.power + equipment.power + type.power) AS powertotal,
        (ancestry.defense + experience.defense + equipment.defense + type.defense) AS defensetotal,
        (ancestry.toughness + experience.toughness + equipment.toughness + type.toughness) AS toughnesstotal,
        (ancestry.morale + experience.morale + equipment.morale + type.morale) AS moraletotal,
        typecostmp, sizecostmp, units.rowid
        FROM units
        JOIN ancestry on units.ancestry = ancestry.ancestry
        JOIN experience on units.experience = experience.experience
        JOIN equipment on units.equipment = equipment.equipment
        JOIN type on units.type = type.type
        JOIN size on units.size = size.size;""")
```

and then one to get the cost using that view:

```
def get_cost(connection, rowid): # returns the stats plus the cost for the unit as a tuple.
    with connection:               # (attack, power, defense, toughness, morale, cost)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        get_stats(connection)
        cursor.execute("""SELECT attacktotal, powertotal, defensetotal, toughnesstotal, moraletotal,
                ((((attacktotal + powertotal + defensetotal + toughnesstotal + (moraletotal*2)) 
                * typecostmp) * sizecostmp) * 10 + 30)
                FROM stats
                WHERE rowid = ?
                """, rowid)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        return result
```

Comment: Make your query a subquery and select all the columns: `SELECT *, <calculated column> FROM (<your query here>)`

Comment: Use a view (or a table with generated columns in recent sqlite versions) to do all the calculations, and select from that instead of the underlying table.

Comment: Shawn's solution worked.

Answer (score 0):

Shawn's solution worked. I now have a function to get the stats first:

```
def get_stats(connection): #creates a new view of all the units' stats
    with connection:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""DROP VIEW IF EXISTS stats;""")
        cursor.execute("""CREATE VIEW stats AS SELECT
        (ancestry.attack + experience.attack + equipment.attack + type.attack) AS attacktotal,
        (ancestry.power + experience.power + equipment.power + type.power) AS powertotal,
        (ancestry.defense + experience.defense + equipment.defense + type.defense) AS defensetotal,
        (ancestry.toughness + experience.toughness + equipment.toughness + type.toughness) AS toughnesstotal,
        (ancestry.morale + experience.morale + equipment.morale + type.morale) AS moraletotal,
        typecostmp, sizecostmp, units.rowid
        FROM units
        JOIN ancestry on units.ancestry = ancestry.ancestry
        JOIN experience on units.experience = experience.experience
        JOIN equipment on units.equipment = equipment.equipment
        JOIN type on units.type = type.type
        JOIN size on units.size = size.size;""")
```

and then one to get the cost using that view:

```
def get_cost(connection, rowid): # returns the stats plus the cost for the unit as a tuple.
    with connection:               # (attack, power, defense, toughness, morale, cost)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        get_stats(connection)
        cursor.execute("""SELECT attacktotal, powertotal, defensetotal, toughnesstotal, moraletotal,
                ((((attacktotal + powertotal + defensetotal + toughnesstotal + (moraletotal*2)) 
                * typecostmp) * sizecostmp) * 10 + 30)
                FROM stats
                WHERE rowid = ?
                """, rowid)
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        return result
```